# C++17 filesystem library recursive_directory_iterator

Tags: c++, c++17, filesystems

I'm working on a C++ pgm to delete 0-length files and empty directories (those containing no files or subdirectories).
Using C++17's filesystem library I have code like

```
string root(path);
vector<string> pathsFileEmpty; // complete paths to 0-length files
vector<string> pathsDirEmpty;  // complete paths to empty directories
auto iterOptions = fs::directory_options::follow_directory_symlink;
for(auto &e : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path, iterOptions))
{
    auto path = e.path();
    if(!e.is_directory() && e.file_size() == 0)
    {
        pathsFileEmpty.push_back(path.string());
    }
    else if(e.is_directory())
    {
        auto d = fs::directory_iterator(path);
        if(begin(d) == end(d))
        {
            pathsDirEmpty.push_back(path.string());
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works correctly. Now I want to add the removal of the 0-length files and empty directories. The latter needs to be done recursively, along the complete path, back to the root if necessary.

My question is, will removing files and directories interfere with the recursive_directory_iterator? If so, I would have to delete the files and directories in multiple passes, which is much less efficient.

Comment: The standard has a non-normative note: "**[fs.class.directory.iterator]/11** *[Note:* If a file is removed from or added to a directory after the construction of a `directory_iterator` for the directory, it is unspecified whether or not subsequently incrementing the iterator will ever result in an iterator referencing the removed or added directory entry. See POSIX `readdir_r`. *-end note]*" My reading is that what you are trying to do - removing a file after it's been enumerated - is safe; removing a file doesn't affect enumeration of other files.

Comment: [The spec for `readdir_r`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/readdir.html) has similar wording. Also of relevance: **[fs.class.rec.dir.itr]/3** The behavior of a `recursive_directory_iterator` is the same as a `directory_iterator` unless otherwise specified.

Comment: While removing a file may be safe, what you quote in the note says that removing a directory is not. So that is my answer, and I shouldn't be using the filesystem iterators at all.

Comment: @Woody20: Or you could use the iterator to compute a list of things to delete and then delete them after building the list.